# Any form for a year-to-date or rolling sum function in Power Query?

Tags: powerquery, m

I'm quite newby to **Power Query**. I have a column for the date, called **MyDate**, format (dd/mm/yy), and another variable called **TotalSales**. Is there any way of obtaining a variable **TotalSalesYTD**, with the sum of year-to-date TotalSales for each row? I've seen you can do that at Power Pivot or Power Bi, but didn't find anything for Power Query.

Alternatively, is there a way of creating a variable **TotalSales12M**, for the rolling sum of the last 12 months of TotalSales?

[image]

Comment: please provide us with sample data and expected results, then I'll assist you quickly...

Comment: That is the sample data you requested

Comment: Where are the other months' sample data? How am I supposed to work out the YTD 12 without data?

Comment: The data format is dd/mm/yy. So you have all the info at the table. The dates are the first day of each month

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to test this properly, but the following code gave me your expected result:

```
let
    initialTable = Table.FromRows({
        {#date(2020, 5, 1), 150},
        {#date(2020, 4, 1), 20},
        {#date(2020, 3, 1), 54},
        {#date(2020, 2, 1), 84},
        {#date(2020, 1, 1), 564},
        {#date(2019, 12, 1), 54},
        {#date(2019, 11, 1), 678},
        {#date(2019, 10, 1), 885},
        {#date(2019, 9, 1), 54},
        {#date(2019, 8, 1), 98},
        {#date(2019, 7, 1), 654},
        {#date(2019, 6, 1), 45},
        {#date(2019, 5, 1), 64},
        {#date(2019, 4, 1), 68},
        {#date(2019, 3, 1), 52},
        {#date(2019, 2, 1), 549},
        {#date(2019, 1, 1), 463},
        {#date(2018, 12, 1), 65},
        {#date(2018, 11, 1), 45},
        {#date(2018, 10, 1), 68},
        {#date(2018, 9, 1), 65},
        {#date(2018, 8, 1), 564},
        {#date(2018, 7, 1), 16},
        {#date(2018, 6, 1), 469},
        {#date(2018, 5, 1), 4}
    }, type table [MyDate = date, TotalSales = Int64.Type]),

    ListCumulativeSum = (numbers as list) as list => 
        let
            accumulator = (listState as list, toAdd as nullable number) as list =>
                let
                    previousTotal = List.Last(listState, 0),
                    combined = listState & {List.Sum({previousTotal, toAdd})}
                in combined,
            accumulated = List.Accumulate(numbers, {}, accumulator)
        in accumulated,

    TableCumulativeSum = (someTable as table, columnToSum as text, newColumnName as text) as table =>
        let
            values = Table.Column(someTable, columnToSum),
            cumulative = ListCumulativeSum(values),
            columns = Table.ToColumns(someTable) & {cumulative},
            toTable = Table.FromColumns(columns, Table.ColumnNames(someTable) & {newColumnName})
        in toTable,

    yearToDateColumn = 
        let
            groupKey = Table.AddColumn(initialTable, "$groupKey", each Date.Year([MyDate]), Int64.Type),
            grouped = Table.Group(groupKey, "$groupKey", {"toCombine", each 
                let
                    sorted = Table.Sort(_, {"MyDate", Order.Ascending}),
                    cumulative = TableCumulativeSum(sorted, "TotalSales", "TotalSalesYTD")
                in cumulative
            }),
            combined = Table.Combine(grouped[toCombine]),
            removeGroupKey = Table.RemoveColumns(combined, "$groupKey")
        in removeGroupKey,
    rolling = Table.AddColumn(yearToDateColumn, "TotalSales12M", each 
        let
            inclusiveEnd = [MyDate],
            exclusiveStart = Date.AddMonths(inclusiveEnd, -12),
            filtered = Table.SelectRows(yearToDateColumn, each [MyDate] > exclusiveStart and [MyDate] <= inclusiveEnd),
            sum = List.Sum(filtered[TotalSales])
        in sum
    ),
    sortedRows = Table.Sort(rolling, {{"MyDate", Order.Descending}})
in
    sortedRows
```

There might be more efficient ways to do what this code does, but if the size of your data is relatively small, then this approach should be okay.

- For the year to date cumulative, the data is grouped by year, then sorted ascendingly, then a running total column is added.
- For the rolling 12-month total, the data is grouped into 12-month windows and then the sales are totaled within each window. The totaling is a bit inefficient (since all rows are re-processed as opposed to only those which have entered/left the window), but you might not notice it.
- `Table.Range` could have been used instead of `Table.SelectRows` when creating the 12-month windows, but I figured `Table.SelectRows` makes less assumptions about the input data (i.e. whether it's sorted, whether any months are missing, etc.) and is therefore safer/more robust.

This is what I get:

[image: Expected result]